# how to exlude a directory from an if-statement to header pages

Tags: php, html, if-statement, header

hello I get crazy through a header-function that does not work.

the idea is that when a user is calling the page foo.php he will be headered. therfor I included a script from script.php

the script reads out the information about the accepted languages from

> $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])

okay, from that I have the preferred language and a country code that I need to header foo.php into the right language direction. the code from script.php is like:

```
if ($pref_language == 'af'){
    header('Location:en'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    exit;
}
if ($pref_language == 'sq'){
    header('Location:en'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    exit;
}
```

so these examples will header foo.php to directory of

> root/en/foo.php

now when calling just script.php that is located in root/scripts/script.php I will headered root/en/scripts/script.php. thats why I would like to add the if-condition that 
all if-statements with header(); only take place for files outside of root/scripts/.

so I added:

```
$filename = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/scripts".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

if (isset($path == false)){

    if ($pref_language == 'af'){
        header('Location:en'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        exit;
    }
    if ($pref_language == 'sq'){
        header('Location:en'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        exit;
    }
}
```

that does not work. so if someone could help me out I really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

Comment: `if(isset($path == false))` ? you're checkin if false is set here. Shouldn't it simply be `if($path)` ?

Comment: I have no idea what it means to "header" something, other than a football. Can you clear up your question?

Comment: it means that the url should not be the $path. so it will exclude the root/scripts/file.ext directory from header.

Comment: I cant understand this: if (isset($path == false)).... it makes no sense. Do you want to see if the variable is set? It is set for sure, just 2 lines above...

Comment: `isset($path == false)` is invalid syntax: `Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression`. Just use `if($path)` in your case.

Comment: @bonny no, it doesn't mean what you think it means

Comment: @damien what would be the right way to do so? thanks

Comment: and $path will be set **ANYWAYS** since it'll contain at least `/scripts` if nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be your solution, although it's kind of silly in a way, but will do the job:

```
<?php

$unwanted_dir = "/scripts";

// this will make sure that the script name doesnt start with "/scripts" 
if (substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strlen($unwanted_dir)) != $unwanted_dir){

    if ($pref_language == 'af'){
        header('Location:en'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        exit;
        }
    if ($pref_language == 'sq'){
        header('Location:en'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        exit;
        }
}
?>
```

another way would be a regular expression, but this is simplier

I advise you to make it more dynamic on selecting the language. i.e:

```
<?php

$unwanted_dir = "/scripts";
$pref_language == 'af';  // dynamicaly set the language
$full_path = '/home/php/site/';

// this will make sure that the script name doesnt start with "/scripts" 
if (substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strlen($unwanted_dir)) != $unwanted_dir){

    if (is_dir($full_path . $pref_language)){
        header('Location:'$full_path . $pref_language . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    }
    else{
        echo "Sorry, we don't support your language";
        // or
        // header('Location:go/to/unsopported/languages.php');
    }

    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: I also advise you to change the if() statements. I add this to the answer ...